# Module.exports in NodeJS, outputting function

Tags: javascript, node.js

**module1.js**

```
module.exports = function (input, input2) {

  return "exported";

};
```

**modulegetter.js**

```
var module1 = require('/Users/Aakarsh/Desktop/Node/ToDo/playground/module1.js');

console.log(module1);
```

**WHAT THIS OUTPUTS:** `[function]`

I want it to output `"exported"` as in the `module1.js` class. What can I do?

**Extra:**

When I have this, in `modulegetter.js`,

```
var f = function (input, input2) {

    return "exp";

};

console.log(f("f", "f"));
```

It outputs `exp` as required, but why doesnt it work with module.exports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually call the function (with or without params):

```
console.log(module1());
```

Comment: What is the difference between `module1` and  `module1()` ??

Comment: `module1()` executes/calls the function, `module1` is only a reference to the function and returns the function itself, not its result/return.

Answer (score 1):

`module.exports` exposes method or variable outside which can be accessed from other file . Imagine you have two files a.js and b.js .

**a.js**

```
var myfunction= function() { ... };
exports.myfunction= myfunction;
```

**b.js**

```
var m = require('./a'); // require includes file by which function will be available
m.myfunction(); // Once function is available you can call 
            //just like normal JavaScript function
```

[Example](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/)